# Xamarin Forms - Output Observable Collection to JSON

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, observablecollection

I have an Observable collection that binds to ListView.

Contents in the Observable Collection contains Product Name, Product Description and Product Price which is displayed in ListView.

There is also additional fields such as Product ID etc that is hidden from the ListView but is in the Observable collection.

There will be multiple items in this Observable collection.

I want to output this observable collection as JSON package so I can submit this via the API.

Here's my code that has the observable collection.

```
public static ObservableCollection<FBProduct> fbproducts = new ObservableCollection<FBProduct>();
```

Here's how I simply add items to the Observable collection.

```
Payment.SelectedProductID = foo.id;
Payment.SelectedProductTitle = foo.title;
Payment.SelectedProductPrice = foo.price;
Payment.SelectedProductFeaturedImage = foo.featured_src;
```

How would I output this Observable collection as a JSON package so It displays something like:

```
"line_items": [
   {
   "product_id": 1234,
   "product_name": apple,
   "product_price": 12,
   "product_description": green apple,
   "quantity": 1
   },
   {
   "product_id": 9876,
   "product_name": pear,
   "product_price": 10,
   "product_description": green pear,
   "quantity": 1
   },
],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [Newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(fbproducts);
```